# Callgrind Anotate not working in OS X 10.10

Tags: c, macos, valgrind, callgrind

i want ask you for some question what can be incorrect,

i write a program in C and translate it in

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic
```

and run

```
valgrind --simulate-cache=yes --tool=callgrind ./a.out
```

that create **callgrind.out.[pid-number]**
and if i run

```
callgrind_annotate callgrind.out.[pid] main.c
```

out will be

---

-- User-annotated source: main.c

---

No information has been collected for main.c

is it any way how to annotate code and calls of function for program optimalize tools ?

note

```
gcc -g - pg progrma.c
```

not working because Apple unsuported debug option on gcc and gprof is unsupported too. And KDE program don`t want run on Mac ...
Thanks everyone to helpful information how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You're compiling with `gprof` profiling information when you compile with `-pg`. valgrind doesn't actually need that data to do it's profiling, what it does need is the debug information.

Using valgrind-HEAD, I took a simple piece of code and compiled it without `-g` and got the same result as you - i.e. `No information has been collected for main.c`.

When I compiled with `-g`, I got useful information about `main.c`, even when I compiled with optimization I got useful information.

Long and short of it is that you need to compile with `-g`, not with `-pg` to get it to work with callgrind.